# Installing ubuntu to a new laptop(asus laptop with Ryzen processor and Vega graphics)

Tags: boot, 20.04, live-usb

I want to install ubuntu into my new laptop (I want to remove my windows completely) , which partition mode  i should use when I create bootable usb(MBR or GPT) , what all thing do i need to be cautious when installing ubuntu to a new laptop .

Comment: I installed recently to a Ryzen laptop. There were no problems at all. But it may depend on other hardware. You don't need to change partition table on your USB drive.

Comment: can you explain how you create a bootable usb.

Comment: I used Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. I didn't bother for anything. Just picked an ISo and made a bootable USB stick.